# REACT NATIVE 3D cube not rendering right on Android. works fine on iOS. z-index problem?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-typescript

I followed this code here: https://github.com/ochanje210/react-native-cube to get a 3D cube that rotates on gesture. However, it doesn't work on Android devices. Any idea how to get it to work?
I also followed this YouTube tutorial on creating the required cube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukL12rEV0Sw. However, after making the necessary changes from typescript to Javascript, I am unable to run it as a JavaScript React native project without errors. The GitHub for this is https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/tree/master/the-10-min/src/Transformation3D

Any help in getting this cube working?